# How to build a shopping list for recipes using dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to build a program that will pick up dictionaries of recipes and the number of ingredients, and then pick up from the user which recipes he wants to make, and print out the shopping list for those recipes.
I built a loop that will absorb all the required recipes and ingredients and I started to build a loop that will absorb the recipes you want to prepare, the problem is that I do not know how to proceed from here, how to remove the ingredients from each list and return to the main program shopping list dictionary.

main:

```
recipes = int(input("How many recipes do you want to enter: "))
recipes_list = []
for i in range(0,recipes):
  recipes_list.append(f.recipes_loop("Enter a product name" , "Enter quantity"))
print(recipes_list)
```

func:

```
def recipes_loop(key_print , value_print):
  my_dict = {}
  print("\n")
  my_dict.update({"name" : str(input("Enter the name of the recipe: ")) })
  elements = int(input("Enter a number of elements in the dict: "))
  for i in range ( elements):
    key = input(f"{key_print}: ") 
    value = input(f"{value_print}: ")
    my_dict.update({key : value})
  return (my_dict)

def shopping_list(recipes_list):
  dish_list = []
  shopping_list = {}
  dish = int(input("How many dishes do you prepare: "))
  for i in range (dish):
    dish_list.append(input("Enter your dish name: "))
  for j in dish_list:
    for d in recipes_list:
     if d["name"] == j :
       shopping_list.update(d)
  print(shopping_list)
```

example input:

```
soup = {'name':'soup', 'potato': 5, 'tomato':4, 'milk':1}
mash = {'name':'mash', 'potato':5, 'milk':1}
desert = {'name':'desert ', 'milk': 1, 'cookies':2}
drink = {'name':'drink', 'milk':1}
```

output when choosing all:

```
{‘potato’:10, ‘tomato’:4, ‘milk’:4, ‘cookies’:2}
```

my main isn't complete yet just because I still don't finish the function
thanks for the helpers

Answer (score 1):

`dict.get()` returns the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to `None`, so that this method never raises a `KeyError`. I set an ingredient default value to 0 if it is not already in the output dictionary.

```
soup = {'name':'soup', 'potato': 5, 'tomato':4, 'milk':1}
mash = {'name':'mash', 'potato':5, 'milk':1}
dessert = {'name':'dessert', 'milk': 1, 'cookies':2}
drink = {'name':'drink', 'milk':1}

l = [soup, mash, dessert, drink]

out = dict()

for r in l:
    for k,v in r.items():
        if k != 'name':
            out[k] = out.get(k, 0) + v
```

**Output**:

```
{'potato': 10, 'tomato': 4, 'milk': 4, 'cookies': 2}
```

Alternatively you could use a `list` comprehension and a `Counter` object:

```
from collections import Counter
   
out = Counter() 
        
for c in [Counter({k:v for k, v in r.items() if k != 'name'}) for r in l]:
    out += c
```

**Output**:

```
dict(out)
{'potato': 10, 'tomato': 4, 'milk': 4, 'cookies': 2}
```

Another option is to use `reduce()` on the `Counter` objects:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce
from collections import Counter

dict(reduce(operator.add, 
            [Counter({k:v for k, v in r.items() if k != 'name'}) for r in l]))
```

**Output**:

```
{'potato': 10, 'tomato': 4, 'milk': 4, 'cookies': 2}
```

**Performance**:

```
2.28 µs ± 71.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
15.4 µs ± 291 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
16 µs ± 357 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

While the result is the same the performance of the first option is much better than others and, at least to me, the code is simpler to read.

Answer (score 0):

To get dictionary that sums all ingredients:

```
recipes_list = [
    {"name": "soup", "potato": 5, "tomato": 4, "milk": 1},
    {"name": "mash", "potato": 5, "milk": 1},
    {"name": "desert ", "milk": 1, "cookies": 2},
    {"name": "drink", "milk": 1},
]

out = {}
for recipe in recipes_list:
    for key, value in recipe.items():
        if key != "name":
            if key in out:
                out[key] += value
            else:
                out[key] = value

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{'potato': 10, 'tomato': 4, 'milk': 4, 'cookies': 2}
```